# how to change navigation focus view of v-date-picker with manual trigger

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datepicker, vuetify.js

i made vue date range picker manually using v-list and v-date-picker :

```
<v-card width="600" elevation="1" rounded>
    <v-container class="pa-0" fluid>
      <v-row dense no-gutters>
        <v-col cols="3" style="height: 100%">
          <v-list>
            <v-list-item-group v-model="select">
              <v-list-item v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i">
                <v-list-item-content>
                  <v-list-item-title v-text="item.time" @click="tes(item.duration)"></v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item-content>
              </v-list-item>
            </v-list-item-group>
          </v-list>
        </v-col>
        <v-divider></v-divider>
        <v-col cols="9">
          <v-date-picker ref="tes" v-model="dates" range full-width>
            <template>
              <v-container class="pa-0">
                <v-row>
                  <v-col cols="6"><YBtn block secondary>Cancel</YBtn></v-col>
                  <v-col cols="6"><YBtn block>Apply</YBtn></v-col>
                </v-row>
              </v-container>
            </template>
          </v-date-picker>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
</v-card>
```

and my script :

```
export default {
data() {
    return {
    select: { time: 'Today', duration: 'today' },
    items: [
        { time: 'Today', duration: 'today' },
        { time: 'Yesterday', duration: 'yesterday' },
        { time: 'This Month', duration: 'thismonth' },
        { time: 'This Year', duration: 'year' },
        { time: 'Previous Month', duration: 'previousmonth' }
    ],
    dates: [this.$moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')]
    }
},

methods: {
    tes(e) {
    switch (e) {
        case 'yesterday':
        this.dates = this.$moment().subtract(1, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
        break
        case 'thismonth':
        this.dates = [
            this.$moment().startOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
            this.$moment().endOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
        ]
        console.log(this.dates)
        break
        case 'year':
        this.dates = [
            this.$moment().startOf('year').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
            this.$moment().endOf('year').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
        ]
        console.log(this.dates)
        break
        case 'previousmonth':
        this.dates = []
        this.dates = [
            this.$moment().startOf('month').subtract(1, 'months').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
            this.$moment().endOf('month').subtract(1, 'months').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
        ]
        console.log(this.dates)
        break
        default:
        this.dates = this.$moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
        break
    }
    }
}
}
```

when i click on previous month, it succesfully change v-date-picker value to the selected previous month. but, the navigation still in current month. how do i change v-date-picker navigation focus to selected previous month?

[as you can see there, the focus navigation at december. what i want when i click prevous month. it showing november, which is the previous selected month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtH9i.png)